# Where in Doha can I learn about Qatar's history and culture, while the National Museum is closed?

Tags: culture, museums, history, qatar, doha

The [website of the National Museum of Qatar](http://www.qm.org.qa/en/project/national-museum-qatar) seems to suggest that when it's re-opened, it'll be an amazing place to find out about the history and culture of Qatar. It should also have an impressive building! Based on what I saw of the building site when my taxi went past earlier, it's shaping up nicely, but certainly not finished...

In the mean time, is there anywhere else I can go in Doha to learn more about the history and culture of Qatar? Any other museums or cultural centres or similar that'll cover at least some of it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to a tip from my hotel, I've discovered there is somewhere open in the mean time - [the Msheireb Enrichment Centre](http://mec.msheireb.com/).

The Msheireb Enrichment Centre is located on a medium sized barge moored off the Corniche, just west of the Sheraton Hotel (the triangular pyramid shaped hotel near the north eastern edge of the Corniche)

The exhibition is sponsored by Msheireb Properties, who've apparently done lots of building works around Doha. No-one seems to know if it'll stay long term, or close when the National Museum re-opens, but for now it's your best bet for a short visit to learn about Qatar's history and culture!

(It's at the other end of the Corniche from the Museum of Islamic Art, but there are public buses running round the Corniche you can take mostly between the two, if you don't fancy the 4.5km seafront walk)